# Can the word ḥōq be correctly interpreted in Isaiah 40:22 as a sphere or a ball?

Tags: hebrew, isaiah, earth

I am not looking for the meaning for the word [ḥōq](https://biblehub.com/text/job/26-10.htm) like [answered here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/52716/what-is-the-circle-of-the-earth-in-isaiah-4022/52724#52724). but if it can be possibly interpreted as a sphere or a ball without being erroneous.

Isaiah 40:22

> He sits enthroned above the circle of the earth, and its people are
> like grasshoppers. He stretches out the heavens like a canopy and
> spreads them out like a tent to live in

Also put in mind that there are verses with a word that means a ball like [Isaiah 22:18](https://biblehub.com/text/isaiah/22-18.htm) has the word "kad-dūr"

So the question is can Ishaiah 40:20 be translated correctly to this as the Arabic bible does ?

> ["He who sits on the **globe**, and its inhabitants are like
> grasshoppers. He who spreads the heavens as a tabernacle, and spreads
> them out as a tent to dwell in.” ( Isaiah 40:22 ).](https://1-st--takla-org.translate.goog/Bibles/BibleSearch/showVerses.php?book=29&chapter=40&vmin=22&_x_tr_enc=1&_x_tr_sl=ar&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp)

All the Arabic versions of the bible translate it as globe while almost all the English translations translate it as circle ... so who is the right one ?

Comment: I am not sure how anything can be added on top of what was said earlier.  The word refers either to the horizon or the dome or vault of heaven.  It does not refer to a ball or sphere.  If they wanted to write "ball" or similar, one might have used the word דּוּר as in Isa 22;18.

Comment: @Dottard Gotcha , So the All the Arabic bibles are in wrong for doing it this way ? ..... But how would horizon attach to "of the earth" I can't foreseen what would it actually mean ....Also isn't the dome thing related to the centralized earth and flat earth ? or ... ?

Comment: See the earlier answer.

Comment: You are confusing two matters - the dome of the sky vs the sphere of the earth - Isa 40:22 is not talking about the sphere of the earth it is talking about the circle of the horizon of the dome of the sky.  You cannot have it both ways.

Comment: "the circle of the horizon of the dome of the sky"  I am absolutely lost ... is there is any image of what does this look like ? but where did the earth word go ? even in the most correct translation on netbible.org/bible/Isaiah+40#  .... it says " He is the one who sits on the earth’s horizon"  not "the circle of the horizon of the dome of the sky"  .... @Dottard

Comment: This is pointless - you believe what you wish the Bible said, not what it says.  See my other comments.

Comment: @Dottard mate, I am not wishing anything I want to know how in the world the arabic bible got it from "circle" / "horizon"  to the "globe"  ,  Also would using "the horizon of the dome of the sky" mean anything about the shape of earth like sphere/ball/circle/flat ... if not. you can add an Answer including the response..... like can it be used to prove whether the earth is  round or flat ? as the arabic bible reading people can't stop about how the bible knew that the earth was a globe and how a miracle it's ... Thanks : )

Comment: @Dottard Please , Just what you said in the comment + no it can't be used as a proof whether the earth is flat nor not .... so i can accept the answer and be done with it. Also hopefully a picture of "the horizon of the dome of the" so anyone who comes across the question can actually get an image of what the verse is trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

The word in question in Isaiah 40:22 is חוּג, *chug*, which appears in at least six other verses:

1. I Samuel 30:16: וְהִנֵּה נְטֻשִׁים עַל פְּנֵי כָל הָאָרֶץ אֹכְלִים וְשֹׁתִים וְ**חֹגְגִים** בְּכֹל הַשָּׁלָל הַגָּדוֹל אֲשֶׁר לָקְחוּ
2. Isaiah 44:13: חָרַשׁ עֵצִים נָטָה קָו יְתָאֲרֵהוּ בַשֶּׁרֶד יַעֲשֵׂהוּ בַּמַּקְצֻעוֹת וּבַ**מְּחוּגָה** יְתָאֳרֵהוּ וַיַּעֲשֵׂהוּ כְּתַבְנִית אִישׁ כְּתִפְאֶרֶת אָדָם לָשֶׁבֶת בָּיִת
3. Psalms 42:5: אֵלֶּה אֶזְכְּרָה וְאֶשְׁפְּכָה עָלַי נַפְשִׁי כִּי אֶעֱבֹר בַּסָּךְ אֶדַּדֵּם עַד-בֵּית אֱלֹהִים בְּקוֹל-רִנָּה וְתוֹדָה הָמוֹן **חוֹגֵג**
4. Psalms 107:27 **יָחוֹגּוּ** וְיָנוּעוּ כַּשִּׁכּוֹר וְכָל-חָכְמָתָם תִּתְבַּלָּע
5. Proverbs 5:27: בַּהֲכִינוֹ שָׁמַיִם שָׁם אָנִי בְּחוּקוֹ **חוּג** עַל-פְּנֵי תְהוֹם
6. Job 22:14: עָבִים סֵתֶר-לוֹ וְלֹא יִרְאֶה וְ**חוּג** שָׁמַיִם יִתְהַלָּךְ

In I Samuel 30:16 it means "they are celebrating", probably because celebrants dance in circles.

In Isaiah 44:13 it means some sort of compass, a tool for drawing circles.

In Psalms 42:5 it means celebrating.

In Psalms 107:27 it refers to the movements of a drunk person - around in circles.

In Proverbs 5:27 it means circling from above like a hawk or vulture circles.

In Job 22:14 it means "the circle of the sky", though this reading is somewhat dependent on the readings in the previous verses.

So it would seem that the usage in question means "circle".

The only use of כדור in the OT is also in Isaiah, but not referring to the sky or the earth. In any event, כדור does not fit verse 40:22 because חוג is used to alliterate with חגבים, grasshoppers, in the continuation of the verse. So it is "circle", like in Job 22:14.

The other word that is used to describe the sky, רקיע, as used in Genesis and commonly translated as "firmament", has connotations of "background", "area", or "platform" or "a flattened area".

Having said all of this, I don't think that the translations to which you refer are incorrect or misleading, except in the word-for-word literal sense, which usually results in poor translation. The sense of the translation that you provide is correct. It would help to understand the translator's reasoning if you could quote the verse here في اللغة العربية or at least state which Arabic translation you are using.

At the time that Isaiah was written there was no science as we know it today. The descriptions of the world are presented as the common person experiences them in the day-to-day Iron Age ancient world, because that is the prophet's audience. There is no descernable intent to make any statement either directly or indirectly about physical reality, only a use of our common perceptions of that reality to make a spiritual point. There is no indication in the language of the OT in general of a concept of a sphere in contrast with something circular. The language of this chapter of Isaiah is poetic and figurative. Word choice in Isaiah is often for alliteratory effect, particularly in this verse. So this verse is open to a wide range of translations and can't be used in any arguments about astronomy or physics as we understand them today.

Comment: Thanks mate for the answer. Can you add the last parts about the possible translation that @Dottard said "the horizon of the dome of the sky" .... A picture of it will do. Also the most accurate translation of the bible on the whole web at netbible translated it as "earth’s horizon" with other possible meanings ... vault (of the heavens) which is what Dottard  said ... about the misleading part or not ... i think that it can be .. cause if the bible guessed the shape of earth right at that time it may be considered a miracle or a way to prove if the earth is flat if circle word used.

Comment: Finally , Can the verse be used to determine/tell/prove the shape of earth , incase of flat earther's or round earth believers ? as such misuse is show here youtu.be/XJZqxH2C-UM?t=1359
@Abu Munir Ibn Ibrahim al Yahud , Thanks

Comment: Also i suggest that you take a look on the verses that mentioned the word... Cause i can't find them too... Click on the wanted word then strong search or word search.... Also even on bible hub... There is only 3 mentions of the word... I think there is an error on your side biblehub.com/hebrew/2329.htm.           |https://netbible.org/reader/bible/Isaiah%2040

Comment: @minanageh Answered your comments in an edit to the reply.

Comment: Dear @Abu Munir Ibn Ibrahim al Yahud .... The word in question "חוּג" which is used as a Noun Masculine in Isaiah 40:22 which is 
the verse in question doesn't use it as a Verb with code name H2329 not H2328 
That leaves us with 3 verses only not 6... |Job 22:14 - Proverbs 8:27 - Isaiah 40:22| 
if you go with the verb one then we only have Job 26:10 but that isn't what we looking for. 
The word "חָגַג" with code name "H2287" in I Samuel 30:16 occurs in over 15 verses !! ... 
Remove Isaiah 44:13 & Psalms 42:5 & Psalms 107:27 from your answer and reformat pls

Comment: Sources: [The Verses with Noun Masculine חוּג H2329 like in the 3 verses](https://www.quotescosmos.com/bible/bible-concordance/H2329.html) ... [another source for it](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/2329.htm) ..... [The Verses with Verb חוּג H2328 like in Job 26:10](https://www.quotescosmos.com/bible/bible-concordance/H2328.html) ....[The verses with the word "חָגַג" with code name "H2287" like in I Samuel 30:16](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/2287.htm)

Comment: Also about the last edit ... it can be summarized in your last sentence `this verse is open to a wide range of translations and can't be used in any arguments about astronomy or physics as we understand them today.`  In addition to a simple language of "no it can't be used to prove the earth is round" .... and an image of the [correct translation](https://netbible.org/bible/Isaiah+40#:~:text=sits%20on%20the-,earth%E2%80%99s%20horizon,-%3B) of the verse `earth's horizon` or `earth's vault of the heavens` would help the readers here grasp a view of what the author had in mind. Thanks

Comment: Searching these words , [this what i found](https://www.google.com/search?q=The+vault+of+the+heavens&tbm=isch&chips=q:the+vault+of+the+heavens,online_chips:bible:HSSN7_ze38Q%3D&hl=en) ... which fits most of OT Verses too

Comment: @ Abu Munir Ibn Ibrahim al Yahud Hello ?